# How to read data from Excel Sheet using Excel VBA 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

While in one Excel sheet I would like to read data from another Excel sheet and write it to a text file.

Example of the first sheet:

```
Sheet_Name   File_Name    Start_Line   End_Line
Sheet1       C:\Test.txt  B5           H10         Button
```

Clicking the button should write Sheet1 cells B5-H10 to C:\Test.txt.

How to do that?

Comment: I have edited your question but is is still unclear. 1) There is no L column in your example - what is it? 2) Where do **B*5 and **H**10 come from? 3) Does the button click need to 'execute' one line or more. Please update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to handle a text file directly

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim shSrc As Worksheet
    Dim rSrc As Range
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim FileNumber As Integer
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long

    Set shSrc = Worksheets(Me.Cells(2, 1).Value)
    dat = shSrc.Range(Me.Cells(2, 3).Value & ":" & Me.Cells(2, 4).Value).Value

    FileNumber = FreeFile
    Open Me.Cells(2, 2).Value For Output As #FileNumber
    For rw = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
    For cl = 1 To UBound(dat, 2)
        Print #FileNumber, dat(rw, cl)
    Next cl, rw
    Close #FileNumber
End Sub
```

Note:

1. Assumes an ActiveX button
2. You will need to add error handling
3. You don't say what layout you want in the text file.  This justs write one cell per line.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the cells you want to save in a .txt into a new sheet, save it as a .txt file and delete the temporary sheet.

Like this:

```
'Copy the range you want to get into a file    

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

'Paste the range to Cells(1,1)    

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= FILEPATH, _
    FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

ActiveSheet.Delete    

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= FILEPATH, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

If you want to get rid of prompts and such, set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning.